# JUNG (Java Graph): How to prevent Vertex- and Edge-Labels from overlapping?

Tags: java, graph, label

I'm currently using [Jung](http://jung.sf.net) to draw graphs (I really mean graphs not charts!).  The problem is that Vertex and Edge Labels are overlapping with the Vertexes and the Edges. This leads into strange looking graphs. The Problem is not bound to a specific Layout-Algorithm (though I've been using FRLayout).

Are there any possibilities to tell JUNG to prevent these overlappings? I hoped this is already implemented and the only problem is to find the right options!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(The following answer assumes Jung2; I'm not familiar with pre-Jung2).

One of Jung's strengths is that it is very extensible, and easily extended.  Jung allows you to plug in various transformers (simple rendering properties), renderers (more complex rendering), and so forth, to customize the behavior when the default isn't quite right.  These are typically installed on the RenderContext (which you can get from your VisualizationViewer).

On the flip side, its drawbacks are its complexity and lack of decent documentation.  If you're going to do any moderate to heavy customization, you'll need to dig into the Jung source.

For example, the vertex label rendering can be customized by plugging in a new vertex label renderer (Renderer.VertexLabel interface).  For example, you can instantiate BasicVertexLabelRenderer and specifying a different position (north, west, center, etc.).  You could put your label at the center, if you are willing to change the shape into something larger than that circle (to do so, install your own vertex shape transformer -- an instance of Transformer).  Alternatively, you could create your own custom implementation of this interface which renders a background under the label text.

You could also install your own tweaked version of Renderer.EdgeLabel (see Jung's BasicEdgeLabelRenderer) to customize the positioning of the edge label.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to set the label offset:

```
vv.getRenderContext().setLabelOffset(20);
```

Where **vv** is your **VisualizationViewer** object.

Answer (score 6):

by the way, if you do want to change the color, at first it appears to be a major pain. but I recently discovered this little trick:

```
Transformer labelTransformer = new ChainedTransformer<String,String>(new Transformer[]{
            new ToStringLabeller<String>(),
            new Transformer<String,String>() {
            public String transform(String input) {
                return "<html><font color=\"yellow\">"+input;
            }}});

context.setVertexLabelTransformer(labelTransformer);
```

Comment: Do you know where this use of HTML is documented in JUNG. In other words what are the possibilities and what are the limitations of using HTML in JUNG?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is just how its implemented, the authors of the code probably don't see it as an issue. The JUNG library is open-source so you are welcome to make changes to it as you see fit.

If you don't want to change the code an easy fix to make the labels more readable would be to simply change the color of the labels, so they differ from the edges.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem of Edge Labels overlapped. A quick and dirty solution I used to position the edge labels is by padding a certain length with white spaces in the string value.

```
//pad some white spaces to value of edge when adding edges to the graph
graph.addEdge(String.format("%-35s", "Edge-A"), 1, 2);
```

It will avoid the edge labels from clouded and overlapped in the centre especially when building a bipartite graph. Hope this helps some of you out there!